# how to get a value from list in php?

Tags: php, html, sql, netbeans, xampp

I'm tring to get the value from a list that represents a star rating after pressing on a submit button.

How do I get the maximum value finaly after the user has rated(in php)?

This is the code of the star rating:

```
<form class="rating" method="post">
  <input id="star_rating" name="star_rating" type="hidden" />
  <ul>
    <li><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw" value="1"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw" value="2"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw" value="3"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw" value="4"></i></li>
    <li><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw" value="5"></i></li>
  </ul>
</form>
```

This is my function (I've tried to get it with the name : "star_rating" using $_POST).

```
<?php
if (isset($_POST["submitRate"])) {
    $pid=$_REQUEST['pid'];
    $uid = $_POST["rateid"];
    $rating = $_POST['star_rating'];
    $rate_re = $_POST['txt_reason'];
    die("Error " . mysqli_error($con));
    $sql = "update userstotasks set reason ='$rate_re' where post_id='$pid' and usr_id='$uid'";
    mysqli_query($con, $sql);           
}
```

So how do I get the chosen value in the star rate into a variable in my php function? 
I thought maybe I have to concatenate the values and take the highest by using foreach?..

Comment: Looks like you need a JS function that updates the hidden input with the selected value from the ul.

Comment: Lists aren't submitted as part of forms, you are going to need some javascript to detect the click and copy the value to the hidden input. Do you have some?

Comment: It'd be alot easier with radio buttons... what's the reasoning for using lists?

Answer (score 2):

You could make it work with radioboxes to limit the user to select one rating. An alternative is using javascript to update the hidden input when a user clicks a rating.

An html only solution:

```
<form class="rating" method="post">
    <ul>
        <li><input type="radio" name="star_rating" value="1" checked/>1 <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw rating_value"></i></li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="star_rating" value="2"/>2 <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw rating_value"></i></li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="star_rating" value="3"/>3 <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw rating_value"></i></li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="star_rating" value="4"/>4 <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw rating_value"></i></li>
        <li><input type="radio" name="star_rating" value="5"/>5 <i class="fa fa-star fa-fw rating_value"></i></li>
    </ul>

    <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

An alternative solution with javascript

```
<form class="rating" method="post">
    <input id="star_rating" name="star_rating" type="hidden" />
    <ul>
        <li><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw rating_value" data-value="1"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw rating_value" data-value="2"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw rating_value" data-value="3"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw rating_value" data-value="4"></i></li>
        <li><i class="fa fa-star fa-fw rating_value" data-value="5"></i></li>
    </ul>
</form>

<script>
    var ratingValues = document.querySelectorAll('.rating_value');
    var startRatingInput = document.querySelector('#star_rating');

    ratingValues.forEach(function(ratingValue){
        ratingValue.addEventListener('click', function(e){
            startRatingInput.value = parseInt(e.currentTarget.dataset.value);
        })
    })
</script>
```

Read more about radioboxes: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/radio